# Why pressing back button inside of cordova WebView closes app?

Tags: android, cordova, android-fragments, android-webview

Given two initialized and added in the backstack fragments  (one of them i see on the screen). Each fragment has CordovaWebView as view. In one web view i have loaded "www.google.com" in another "www.bing.com". Now, if I press a back button - i am awaiting, that the fragment with "www.bing.com" will be poped from the stack and I will see google site on my device screen. Instead of this, the app immediately exits (for a very short time I can see google.com, but then app completly exits)

**small part of Activity:**

```
cordova.getActivity().getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.fragment_container, webViewFragmentGoogle)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();


cordova.getActivity().getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.fragment_container, webViewFragmentBing)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mUrl = "file:///android_asset/www/main.html";
    private CordovaWebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_fragment,container, false);

        if (view != null)
            mWebView = (CordovaWebView)view; 


        Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 
        String iframeUrl = bundle.getString("iframeUrl");


        if (!mUrl.isEmpty())
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl(iframeUrl);

        }



        return view;
    }


    public void goToUrl(String url) {

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mWebView!= null) {
            mWebView.handleResume(true, false);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mWebView != null)
        {
            mWebView.handlePause(true);
        }  
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mWebView != null)
        {
            mWebView.handlePause(true);
            mWebView.handleDestroy();
        }  

        super.onDestroy();

    }   


}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of CordovaWebView.onKeyUp() logic - it intercepts your key strokes and hooks some actions on them: in this case action is:

```
this.cordova.getActivity().finish();
```

Personally I also find killing my activity a bit intrusive, especially in case, when I cannot configure it in any way. Please check [CordovaWebView messes up with onBackPressed method in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400408/cordovawebview-messes-up-with-onbackpressed-method-in-android) for some details.