# CordovaWebView messes up with onBackPressed method in android

Tags: java, android, cordova

As title says `CordovaWebView` and `onBackPressed` in android in combination are giving weird results.
I have hybrid app. My main activity has `DrawerLayout` and `CordovaWebView`.
My onBackPressed:

```
 @Override

public void onBackPressed(){
  if(drawerIsOpen){
    //close drawer
  }else if(webviewIsIn){
     //hide webview
  }else{
     super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

When I use android's `WebView` the overridden method is called as expected. And when I change to `CordovaWebView` the method wouldn't even get called, instead native `onBackPressed` would be called instead. 
I have tried overriding `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` but it gives me the same result, the methods are just not being called. 
I'm using Cordova 2.9.0 and testing device is Galaxy Note 2, Android jellybean 4.2.2
`DrawerLayout` has the close on back pressed functionality I've just disabled it.
I hope you guys can understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue. My solution was to derive from `CordovaWebView` and override `public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` with something like this (for Cordova 3.4.0, the code is a part of the `CordovaWebView.onKeyUp(int, KeyEvent)`):

```
public class CustomCordovaWebView extends CordovaWebView {

    protected View mCustomView;

    protected boolean bound;

    public CustomCordovaWebView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCordovaWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomCordovaWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    public CustomCordovaWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle, final boolean privateBrowsing) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle, privateBrowsing);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If back key
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // A custom view is currently displayed  (e.g. playing a video)
            if (mCustomView!=null){
                this.hideCustomView();
            }else{
                // The webview is currently displayed
                // If back key is bound, then send event to JavaScript
                if (this.bound) {
                    this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('backbutton');");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // If not bound
                    // Go to previous page in webview if it is possible to go back
                    if (this.backHistory()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    // If not, then invoke default behavior
                    else {
                        //this.activityState = ACTIVITY_EXITING;
                        //return false;
                        // If they hit back button when app is initializing, app should exit instead of hang until initialization (CB2-458)
                        // this.cordova.getActivity().finish();
                        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this thing is closing your activity in CordovaWebView
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void hideCustomView() {
        mCustomView = null;
        super.hideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public void showCustomView(final View view, final WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
        mCustomView = view;
        super.showCustomView(view, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindButton(final boolean override) {
        bound = override;
        super.bindButton(override);
    }
}
```

If there is a better solution, I would be interested in it.

Comment: Sadly this answer is not solving my problem.

Comment: My snippet was for Cordova 3.4.0, so plain reusing will probably not work on 2.9.0. Please try to check with 2.9.0 sources of the the CordovaWebView to adapt this approach. I can check it by myself later, but I will probably not have a chance to test it anyway.

Comment: I did change according to my needs. Interesting thing is that when calling clearHistory on cord web view the bug seems to be appearing not so often. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: no longer supports 5.1.1 as the CordovaWebView is an interface and not a class anymore.